# Eigenvector of $\begin{equation} {A}=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \end{equation}$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[Edited] I find an eigenvalue, of $\begin{equation}
  {A}=\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 0 \\
    2 & 2 & 0 \\
    1 & 2 & 2     
      \end{bmatrix}
 \end{equation}$,
is $\lambda=2$ that is multiplicity three and a corresponding eigenvector is $v={[0\; 0\; 1]}^T$ (I agree, any $a*v, a\in R, a \neq 0$ is eigenvector relative to $\lambda=2$).
Are there any other eigenvectors? Thank you.
(I appreciate the valuable suggestions from Sassatelli Giulio, KBS and Turquoise Tilt)

Comment: Since A*v = 2*v, I think v is an eigenvector for A. Right?

Comment: $Av$ is not equal to $2v$.

Comment: Rank of (A-2I)=2 and hence nullity =1. Hence there is only one eigen vector.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

An eigevector relative to the only eigenvalue $\lambda = 2$ for $A$, is $v = ( 0, 0, 1)$ because if you do the calculation
$$ Av = 2 v$$
As the definition of eigenvector. "Is the only one?" No each vector of the form $v_x = ( 0,0,x), \space x\in \mathbb{R}$ are eigenvector relative to $\lambda = 2$, in fact $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, v_x \in { E=\left\{v :\left(A-2 I\right)v = 0 \right\}}$ that is the eigenspace relative to $\lambda = 2$

Comment: Thank you so much.